# Does anyone know the name of this conjecture?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, conjectures

Given $p$ and $q$ are two different prime numbers.
Does there exist a positive integer $n$ such that
$p^n = 1 \pmod q$

Is this conjecture true? If so, any source of the prove. What is the name of this conjecture or theorem (if it is true)?

Answer (score 2):

This is true. Take $n = q - 1$. This is Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: which is just a specific case, of the more general Euler's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Independently of *Fermat*,  it simply results from the  fact that the group of units $(\mathbf Z/q\mathbf Z)^\times$ is finite, hence the (multiplicative) subgroup generated by  the congruence class $\bar p=p+q\mathbf Z$ is finite.